# Create qnode with density matrix on pennylane

Tags: density-matrix, pennylane, programming, quantum-fisher-information

I'm using pennylane.

What I want to do is

1. Create a `qnode` with the 2*2 density matrix of a single qubit one. It has the parameter as phi

- Given density matrix:
  $$\frac{1}{\gamma\cos(\varphi)+(\gamma-2)\mathrm{e}^{\frac{t}{t_2}}}\begin{pmatrix}(\gamma-1)\left(\mathrm{e}^{\frac{t}{t_2}}+\cos(\varphi)\right)&\mathrm{i}\sqrt{1-\gamma}\sin(\varphi)\\-\mathrm{i}\sqrt{1-\gamma}\sin(\varphi)&\cos(\varphi)-\mathrm{e}^{\frac{t}{t_2}}\end{pmatrix}$$

2. Pass is to `qml.qinfo.classical_fisher()`. I want to calculate classical fisher information respect to phi.

But the problem is that when I create qnode with density matrix and pass it to `qml.qinfo.classical_fisher()` it shows the following error:

```
DeviceError: Gate QubitDensityMatrix not supported on device default.qubit.autograd
```

Is there any possible method to define a `qnode` with a custom density matrix available to use with autograd?

I tried to convert it to a state vector but since the density matrix is a mixed state it can't be converted to state vector.

Here is my code:

````
import pennylane as qml
from pennylane import numpy as np

t1, t2, gamma = 1, 1, 0.5

# Define the density matrix
def rho_ps(phi):
    density_matrix_ps = np.array([
        [(gamma - 1)*(np.exp(t1/t2) + np.cos(phi)), 1.j * np.sqrt(1-gamma)*np.sin(phi)],
        [-1.j * np.sqrt(1-gamma)*np.sin(phi), np.cos(phi) - np.exp(t1/t2)]]) / (gamma*np.cos(phi) + (gamma-2)*np.exp(t1/t2))

    return density_matrix_ps

n_wires = 1
dev = qml.device("default.qubit", wires=n_wires)

# Define the qnode with density matrix
@qml.qnode(dev)
def circ(params):
    density_matrix = rho_ps(params)
    qml.QubitDensityMatrix(density_matrix, wires=0)  # Initialize the qubit with the density matrix

    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(0))

# Generate parameters used in classical fisher information
params = np.array([np.pi])
CFIM = qml.qinfo.classical_fisher(circ)

print(CFIM)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer mistakenly read `quantum_fisher` instead of `classical_fisher`. It is actually possible to compute the latter with mixed states, but not the former.

It seems that there are three problems in your code:

- The device you use should be `default.mixed`, since the density matrix you care about is mixed.
- `params` should be differentiable, and should thus be created with `requires_grad=True`
- `CFIM` must be called on `params`, as it's a function

All in all, the following code gives you what you want (If I'm not mistaken):

```
import pennylane as qml
from pennylane import numpy as np

t1, t2, gamma = 1, 1, 0.5

# Define the density matrix
def rho_ps(phi):
    density_matrix_ps = np.array([
        [(gamma - 1)*(np.exp(t1/t2) + np.cos(phi)), 1.j * np.sqrt(1-gamma)*np.sin(phi)],
        [-1.j * np.sqrt(1-gamma)*np.sin(phi), np.cos(phi) - np.exp(t1/t2)]]) / (gamma*np.cos(phi) + (gamma-2)*np.exp(t1/t2))

    return density_matrix_ps

dev = qml.device("default.mixed", wires=[0])

@qml.qnode(dev)
def circ(params):
    density_matrix = rho_ps(params)
    qml.QubitDensityMatrix(density_matrix, wires=0)

    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(0))

params = np.array([np.pi], requires_grad=True)
CFIM = qml.qinfo.transforms.classical_fisher(circ)
print(CFIM(params))
```

Comment: Thanks. I posted it on github [link](https://github.com/PennyLaneAI/pennylane/issues/4587)

Comment: @Dongukkim I've realized that my previous answer wasn't right for your use case, as you want to use `classical_fisher`, and not the quantum one. I think it is doable in this case, please see my edited answer

Comment: I just changed  "defualt.qubit" -> "default.mixed" as you mentioned and it just perfectly works. Thanks for excellent job!!!

Comment: @Dongukkim Glad that helped!